# Python script for serving an xml file on a port not working

Tags: python, sockets, service, applet, port

Okay, so to make it simple I have a file located in the same folder named flashpolicy.xml which I would like to serve on port 843.  I have absolutely no experience with python but have done several other languages and this is my latest attempt at merging some other peoples code and trying to make it work.  I can run this script currently and it will register the service correctly, I can start the service and if I do a netstat -na I do see that the correct port is LISTENING. The error log indicates that the last line running in my version is:
thread.start_new_thread(self.handle, self.sock.accept())

---

```
import pythoncom
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import servicemanager
import socket
import sys
import optparse
import thread
import exceptions
import contextlib
import logging


class AppServerSvc (win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "flaspsrv"
    _svc_display_name_ = "Flash Policy Server"
    _svc_description_ = "Initialize Flash Policy Server"

    def __init__(self,args):
        logging.basicConfig(filename='C:\\Uploads\\testing.log', level=logging.DEBUG, filemode='a', format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self,args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None,0,0,None)
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(60)

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                              servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
                              (self._svc_name_,''))
        self.main()

    def main(self):
        try:
            self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        except AttributeError:
            # AttributeError catches Python built without IPv6
            self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        except socket.error:
            # socket.error catches OS with IPv6 disabled
            self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
            logging.info('Listening on port 843')
            self.sock.bind(('', 843))
            self.sock.listen(5)

        try:
            while True:
                thread.start_new_thread(self.handle, self.sock.accept())
        except socket.error, e:
            logging.info('Error accepting connection: %s' % (e[1],))

    def handle(self, conn, addr):
        logging.info('Temp2')
        addrstr = '%s:%s' % (addr[0],addr[1])
        try:
            logging.info('Connection from %s' % (addrstr,))
            with contextlib.closing(conn):
                # It's possible that we won't get the entire request in
                # a single recv, but very unlikely.
                request = conn.recv(1024).strip()
                if request != '<policy-file-request/>\0':
                    logging.info('Unrecognized request from %s: %s' % (addrstr, request))
                    return
                logging.info('Valid request received from %s' % (addrstr,))
                fo = open('flashpolicy.xml', 'rb')
                str=fo.read()
                conn.sendall(str)
                logging.info('Sent policy file to %s' % (addrstr,))
        except socket.error, e:
            logging.info('Error handling connection from %s: %s' % (addrstr, e[1]))
        except Exception, e:
            logging.info('Error handling connection from %s: %s' % (addrstr, e[1]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(AppServerSvc)
```

oh and i suppose it would be helpful to see the original script which I know works 100% correct:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
# flashpolicyd.py
# Simple socket policy file server for Flash
#
# Usage: flashpolicyd.py [--port=N] --file=FILE
#
# Logs to stderr
# Requires Python 2.5 or later

from __future__ import with_statement

import sys
import optparse
import socket
import thread
import exceptions
import contextlib

VERSION = 0.1

class policy_server(object):
    def __init__(self, port, path):
        self.port = port
        self.path = path
        self.policy = self.read_policy(path)
        self.log('Listening on port %d\n' % port)
        try:
            self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        except AttributeError:
            # AttributeError catches Python built without IPv6
            self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        except socket.error:
            # socket.error catches OS with IPv6 disabled
            self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.sock.bind(('', port))
        self.sock.listen(5)
    def read_policy(self, path):
        with file(path, 'rb') as f:
            policy = f.read(10001)
            if len(policy) > 10000:
                raise exceptions.RuntimeError('File probably too large to be a policy file',
                                              path)
            if 'cross-domain-policy' not in policy:
                raise exceptions.RuntimeError('Not a valid policy file',
                                              path)
            return policy
    def run(self):
        try:
            while True:
                thread.start_new_thread(self.handle, self.sock.accept())
        except socket.error, e:
            self.log('Error accepting connection: %s' % (e[1],))
    def handle(self, conn, addr):
        addrstr = '%s:%s' % (addr[0],addr[1])
        try:
            self.log('Connection from %s' % (addrstr,))
            with contextlib.closing(conn):
                # It's possible that we won't get the entire request in
                # a single recv, but very unlikely.
                request = conn.recv(1024).strip()
                if request != '<policy-file-request/>\0':
                    self.log('Unrecognized request from %s: %s' % (addrstr, request))
                    return
                self.log('Valid request received from %s' % (addrstr,))
                conn.sendall(self.policy)
                self.log('Sent policy file to %s' % (addrstr,))
        except socket.error, e:
            self.log('Error handling connection from %s: %s' % (addrstr, e[1]))
        except Exception, e:
            self.log('Error handling connection from %s: %s' % (addrstr, e[1]))
    def log(self, str):
        print >>sys.stderr, str

def main():
    parser = optparse.OptionParser(usage = '%prog [--port=PORT] [--file=FILE]',
                                   version='%prog ' + str(VERSION))
    parser.add_option('-p', '--port', dest='port', type=int, default=843,
                      help='listen on port PORT', metavar='PORT')
    parser.add_option('-f', '--file', dest='path', type="string", default="flashpolicy.xml",
                      help='something FILE', metavar='FILE')
    opts, args = parser.parse_args()
    if args:
        parser.error('No arguments are needed. See help.')
    if not opts.path:
        parser.error('File must be specified. See help.')

    try:
        policy_server(opts.port, opts.path).run()
    except Exception, e:
        print >> sys.stderr, e
        sys.exit(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This is a lot of code to review. Maybe narrow down the scope of the question so we can review a little less code.

Comment: I've done quite a bit of research since and it appears that there were several errors on my part as expected.. I got error logging to work properly to a log file and it appears that it is getting stuck at this line:
thread.start_new_thread(self.handle, self.sock.accept())

directly before that line will write to the error log, which im still researching the thread class but it appears that its just calling the handle and a comment on line 1 of the handle def does not print to log so it is not making it to there... Maybe this helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working through several different attempts/versions of this, I tried using the following steps to install the original working python script as a service:

http://www.tacktech.com/display.cfm?ttid=197

Upon doing so, when I would start my service it would provide me a message that it started and then stopped.  I thought as the example was using an extention of a .exe that a .py extention may not be valid, so I downloaded py2exe and converted my python script into an executable, however this STILL did not correct the problem.  Ultimately, I have concluded that this particular script does not want to install as a service, but I did find a way to make it run invisibly which was my ultimate goal.

To do so (in a Windows), I created a one line VBS file named invisible.vbs as follows:

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False
```

In order to execute this file, I created the following file which I added to my Startup folder:

```
wscript "C:\Uploads\invisible.vbs" "C:\Uploads\flashpolicyd.py"
```

However, if anyone needs to do something similarly, you can just manually type the above command into a command prompt assuming you have the wscript module (Windows Based Script Host).